# MYSQL: Getting all results from last week starting Monday)

Tags: mysql, date

```
CREATE TABLE `sport_data` (
      `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
      `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `sport` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `musclePlan` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `sport_time` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `kcal` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

How can i get all data from this table from the last week (from Monday to Sunday)?

I have tried:

```
WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+5 DAY AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-2 DAY
```

I don't know if this is correct that way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to do it? What result did you get?

Comment: The result is right, but because i don't understand the syntax i want to ask if its correct? :)

Comment: This approach wouldn't work.  Look at 4/22/2018 and you'll see why the current where wouldn't work.  I'm unsure by what you mean by last week.  if today is 2018/4/22 what dates would you want back and if today was 2018/4/23?

Answer (score 0):

The `>=` and `<` pattern is what we usually use. That part looks right.

I think the question is about the *expressions* that returning the range start and end values.

I suggest that we test those expressions for a variety of date values, not just `CURDATE()`. We can use a value in place of `CURDATE()`, and check the results, and do that for a series of date values.

Conveniently, those expressions will evaluate the same in a `SELECT` list as they do in a `WHERE` clause. So we can run a `SELECT` statement, and check the results.

For example:

```
SELECT t.dt                                      AS dt
     , t.dt - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(t.dt)+5 DAY     AS _ge
     , t.dt - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(t.dt)-2 DAY     AS _lt
  FROM (
         SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS dt
         UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL -1 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL -2 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL -3 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL -4 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL -5 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL -6 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL -7 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL -8 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL -9 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL -10 DAY
       ) t
```

If the expressions are returning the values we expect, in accordance with the specification, for each possible date value, then the expressions are right.

If the expressions are returning values that don't meet the spec, then we need to make adjustments.  Note that an expression that "works" on a Wednesday date might not "work" on a Sunday date.)

Comment: I always want to data from last week (Monday to Sunday) no matter what day is today :) How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO: Showing 3 approaches and why current doesn't work.](http://rextester.com/EOMO37971)

If we assume by "last week" you mean the last full week Monday - Sunday of a week prior to the day you're presently on...

So if today was 20180422, you'd want 20180409-20180415

```
SELECT *
FROM SO50026532_sport_data
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Today:=curdate()) z
WHERE date >= @today - interval (6 + case when dayofweek(@today)=1 then 7 else dayofWeek(@today)-1 end) day
  and date <=@today - interval (case when dayofweek(@today)=1 then 7 else dayofWeek(@today)-1 end) day;
```

Or if your a fan of the >= and < then

```
SELECT *
FROM SO50026532_sport_data
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Today:=curdate()) z
WHERE date >= @today - interval (6 + case when dayofweek(@today)=1 then 7 else dayofWeek(@today)-1 end) day
  and date <@today - interval (case when dayofweek(@today)=1 then 7 else dayofWeek(@today)-1 end-1) day;
```

in the 2nd example we had to subtract by 1 since dayofweek isn't a 0 based.  Of course I could have just date shifted everything down 2 and set sunday to 6... then I wouldn't' need to subtract by 1. and then we'd be adding 7 instead of 6 on the 1st part of the where.  (demo has these 3 and your initial example showing what happens on 4/22.

[Dayofweek](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) starts  on Sunday being 1.  So I use a case statement to shift 1 to 7 and and all the others down 1 giving us Monday = 1 and sunday = 7

The cross join to derived table z was so I could control the curdate() easier and test.  You could replace the variable with curdate() if you want and eliminate the cross join and derived table.

The first where clause subtracts 6 days (1 week and then the # of days from current date back to monday.  This ensures we always start 1 week back from current date and on a monday.  then we only get dates to the Sunday of that week.